# parallel python not discovering worker nodes

Tags: python-2.7, parallel-processing, parallel-python

I am trying to implement a basic pp example as shown below (**SCRIPT1**).

```
import pp

ppservers = ("*",)  # autodiscovery mode on!

# create the job server
job_server = pp.Server(ppservers=ppservers)

for computer, cpu_count in job_server.get_active_nodes().iteritems():
    print "Found {} with CPU count {}!".format(computer, cpu_count)
```

**Environment Details**
OS : windows10
python version : 2.7 (on machine 1 and machine 2)
machine1 IP : 192.168.1.4
machine2 IP : 192.168.56.1

**Steps followed till now** :

1. machine1 and machine2 are connected in same network using wifi
2. **SCRIPT1** is placed on machine1 (machine1 is job server)
3. installed pp in machine2(worker node) and started server on machine2 (port 60000) using

   ```
    python ppserver.py -a
   ```
4. triggered **SCRIPT1** on machine1, machine 1 output is as shown below

```
Found local with CPU count 8!
```

But output at step4 is expected to also detect machine 2 and show output as

```
Found 192.168.56.1:60000 with CPU count 2!
Found local with CPU count 4!
```

A newbie to parrallel computing, how do i debug this ?
Appreciate any kinda pointers for this.

Answer (score 0):

Firewall and virtualBox was the issue.

Steps followed to get to the fix:

1. ping `xxx.xxx.x.x.` (machine1 IP)
2. run ppserver on same machine1 and see if jobserver can list the same machine1 as a worker node

if 1 and 2 is the issue, it is mostly caused by firewall, in this case add an inbound rule for the required port and continue.